# Cannot implicitly convert type 'MongoDB.Driver.ReplaceOneResult' to 'T'

Tags: c#, mongodb, generics

I'm using MongoDB in my WinForm project and am creating a utility function that I could use to `upsert` records in database.

Here's the method so far:

```
public async Task<T> UpdateRoomType<T>(string table, string roomTypeName, T record) 
{
    var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(table);

    var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(Constants.ROOM_TYPE, roomTypeName);

    var result =  await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(
        filter,
        record,
        new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true }
        );

    return result;
}
```

However I'm getting a build error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'MongoDB.Driver.ReplaceOneResult' to 'T'

How do I fix this function to properly return the upserted record to the caller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the appropriate type:

```
public async Task<ReplaceOneResult> UpdateRoomType<T>(string table, string roomTypeName, T record)
                        ^
                        |
```

The error tells you that you are returning an object of type: `MongoDB.Driver.ReplaceOneResult` which seems to be:

```
return result;
```

But in your method you declare the return type as `T`:

```
public async Task<T> UpdateRoomType<T>
```

hence the error.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That fixes the error. However I'd also like to return the upserted data to the caller. Is there any way to get that from `ReplaceOneResult`? For example, if I passed in a `User` object as my `T record` argument, I'd like to return the upserted `User` object to the caller.

Comment: @fishhau " any way to get that from ReplaceOneResult?" unfortunately I have never used mogoDb, So I cannot tell you. But it seems that the inserted value is `T record` am I correct? and this value is passed into the method from outside. Why would you want to return it again? the caller of the method is inevitably in the posession of this object...

Comment: Good point. I guess that makes sense. It's just that the `Insert` method I've used before returns the data while the Replace I used above returns `ReplaceOneResult`. I was hoping to make it consistent. Anyway this should be good. Thank you.

Comment: @fishhau you should rather return a bool, to signal that the replacement has worked. But this would require a little more programming.